# ListView.builder not showing correct list

Tags: dart, flutter

I've created a small app to add items in list, however when i delete something from list, it gets deleted successfully but ListView.builder doesn't show correct values. i know its something related to keys given to class but i'm pretty new in flutter so don't know how to do that.

Gist: https://gist.github.com/OculusMode/213052325ec725aad3ab92c73599b187

Thanks in advance.!

Comment: Hi i'm not really pro with flutter either :) but i changed your Widget to Stateless and things are doing fine right now , i think it has sth to do with state being immutable (not sure though :P ) gonna try to mess with it a bit more for now :) i posted the code as a comment for you on github.

Comment: https://flutter.io/widgets-intro/#keys
Without keys, the first entry in the current build would always sync with the first entry in the previous build, even if, semantically, the first entry in the list just scrolled off screen and is no longer visible in the viewport.
i think i've found sth usefull :))

Answer (score 2):

Add this to constructor of your Widget:

```
:super(key:new ObjectKey(_data))
```

Example:

```
class TodoTile extends StatefulWidget {
  String _data;
  int _index;
  ValueChanged<int> onDelete;
  TodoTile(this._data,this._index,{ @required this.onDelete , Key key}):super(key:new ObjectKey(_data));
  TodoTileState createState() {return new TodoTileState(_data, _index,this.onDelete);}

}
```

Not sure if this would cause problems too but I've also changed widget.onDelete to onDelete (passing the function pointer to the state too)

Source:
https://flutter.io/widgets-intro/#keys